# What are the benefits of showing "Your download will begin in x seconds"?

Tags: html, download

Are there technological benefits when presenting a "download page" that gives a message like the following?

> Your download should automatically
>   begin in a few seconds, but if not,
>   click here.

Is there some bandwidth or server efficiencies with this? Or is it for the benefit of the user somehow?  Why not just have your download link href's go straight to the url of the download?

[Example page](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/products/download.html?product=firefox-3.6&os=win&lang=en-US) (one of a billion)

Comment: Advertising space

Comment: See also: http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/13897/17023

Comment: Ironically, most voted answers point to advertising as the main reason (...but the link provided in the original question does not contain any ads). IMHO, the answer by @David Kolar provides a technical motivation that sounds very reasonable https://stackoverflow.com/a/2142842/11298742

Answer (score 42, accepted):

- Advertising
- SEO benefits, you minimize the links to non html pages of your source page
- you can present similar downloaded products ...
- time for your Content Delivery Network to cache the download, if you point the user to a file not-yet-cached by the CDN

Comment: ...without having to use robots.txt or Google's sitemap stuff?

Comment: Edited my post. But will respond. If you have a bunch of non-html href's on a page, Google rates that as an dead-end, and doesn't give much rank to it. Obviously you can put another page, and have that be the dead-end page with bunch of ads, outbound links etc...

Comment: I chose your answer because I felt like it gave the most info related to possible benefits. Thanks. I actually learned some stuff.

Comment: Another one that wasn't mentioned is if a user accidentally cancels or closes the browser's download window. Without the download link a user would have to refresh the page which sometimes isn't so easy depending on how you arrived at the download page.

Answer (score 18):

Advertising space.

Comment: Yep, it's all about ad space and dollar signs

Comment: Not that I'm fond of ads, but well, everybody's got to pay their bills somehow, don't they? If you want an ad-free Internet, be prepared to open your purse on every junction.

Comment: I'm not judging, just sayin'.  Download.com (c|net) charges premiums to software authors to get better listings and usage statistics.  So there are alternate revenue streams.

Comment: I love the guy who grabs a comment, turns it into an answer, and gets a 100 rep points for being so brilliant.  Nice job.

Answer (score 11):

The benefit is not to the user, but to the site. They are forcing you to stare at their "download landing page" for a few seconds, while they show you ads. Furthermore, with that kind of chicanery, they can prevent the file in question from being directly indexed by search engines, while permitting the download landing page to be indexed.

Comment: Which is perfectly fine and legitimate for a site that generates revenue from ads IMO.

Comment: Yeah, sure, it's "legitimate". It's also "annoying", "user-hostile", and "just plain silly".

Answer (score 8):

If the site is telling you to wait a specific number of seconds before continuing, as you describe in the title, then it's likely all about advertising. But that's not the case with the Mozilla Firefox link you posted within your question. Here, I think the main point is to tell the user to be patient if the download doesn't start immediately, which it might not since it's an additional HTTP request that could be delayed for any number of reasons, including the download server being overloaded. That connection could be reset and the download might never happen. The message is trying to set appropriate expectations for the user: the download might not start this instant, but if it has been more than a few seconds and nothing has happened, then there was probably a problem and here's a link you can click.

There's also a lot of JavaScript in this page that tries to help with the download, and if that fails, the "click here" link should act as a failsafe.

Comment: Thanks for giving an answer to the firefox question.

Answer (score 3):

For once you get additional advertising space. By delaying the download, you give the user some time to recognize and potentially click on the ads.

However a page like this can also be useful when you are offering lots of files. By presenting the user with a message stating exactly what they are going to download shortly, some might actually cancel their downloads by navigating back from that site. If the files you offer are big, this might actually save you some bandwidth.

Moreover you prevent the file from getting indexed directly in search engines, potentially bypassing your site completely. But you can let the search engines index your download pages with all the information *about* the downloads in them. This is related to the advertising topic, but also helps to keep your internal download structure hidden from the search engine. Should you decide to change it, there will be no broken links in search results.

Often you will also find a mirror selection on these interstitial pages. Users can conveniently use the time they have there to choose a different mirror than your suggested default. Should a link be broken, i. e. the mirror does not have the file (yet/anymore), by just hitting the Back button they can conveniently select a different one and try again.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason why getting to a download takes as many steps as it does with most big download providers is indeed gaining page views, and producing ad impressions.

On the other hand, the "please wait" message has a real function IMO: The user is clearly shown that there should now follow a file download, and if redirection to the file download fails - for example because the link's broken, the server is overburdened or whatever - there is a way to try again, or to get help - important especially for less experienced users.

Answer (score 2):

Advertising.

Prevents trivial automated downloads (think wget).

Comment: +1 for "automated downloads". In other words: Webmasters can protect their download servers from "hotlinked" downloads by checking the referer, or dynamically generating a temporary download link.

Answer (score 1):

It also provides a soft landing (in the form of a splash screen, instructions, info...and advertising :) in the event that the browser does not react as anticipated.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some reasons:

SEO: 
Less page bounce & exit rates because you stay longer. (Very important)

Ads: 
They want you to click their ads and support them?

Security: 
Avoid in some degree auto-clickers, hot-linking and similar activities.

Content:
Allow CDN and server to fully load the page before the button appears.

If you are a publisher the delay have to many benefits. For users that don't like them simply leave the page.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to all the answers above, an async download won't show that it started until "something" is returned from the server.  If you clicked the download button and nothing visual happened for 1.3 seconds, you'd start pumping the download button.  In the example site of the original post, I see the web developer chose to make the download button disappear after it was clicked - meaning even the message wasn't enough to stop users from power-clicking.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to build such a page for a JS RIA. Here's why:

- The original idea was to use a hidden iframe inside the RIA. But our company uses a virus scanner/firewall that sends a 302 HTTP response, then using a framebreaker script to present a fullscreen scanning progress page.
- Thus, the download needs to be opened in a new window, since we don't want the RIA to be terminated when a download starts.
- For usability, we **don't want blank popup-windows** for every download (this is actually a problem [others see too](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Download_launches_blank_window)), so we need to show the user *some* HTML content, then redirect to the actual download.
- As @DavidKolar [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2142842/27862), the wording just tells the user to be patient while the download is being prepared.
- We don't use the "click here" part. As for the example page in the question, it's funny to see that Mozilla removed it there too.